# Cannot read property 'omitFormat' of undefined

Tags: sails.js, clickhouse

I created a table in `clickhouse` like below :

```js
let clickhouse = new ClickHouse (sails.config.clickhouse);
let query = `CREATE TABLE table1(category String,subcategory String,title String,id Int64) Engine=Log`
```

and I tried to run the query above as so:

```js
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            clickhouse.query (query, function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
                resolve('success');
            });
        });
let test = await createTable();
```

But then I got this error:

> Cannot read property 'omitFormat' of undefined

Any solution to this error? Thanks

P.S: I've tried to run the query in `Clickhouse` client and it works.

Comment: It's an nodejs error. Check a driver documentation.
probably for create statements it should be another call `await ch.querying("CREATE DATABASE test")`

https://github.com/apla/node-clickhouse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass not initialized *sails.config.clickhouse*-param.

Passing the undefined [options](https://github.com/apla/node-clickhouse#new-clickhouseoptions-options) to ClickHouse-constructor leads to the error in this [line](https://github.com/apla/node-clickhouse/blob/cc30b25b2581f29a5734efa00262a93770c5db66/src/clickhouse.js#L257).

Look at the console to see the related warning:

```
> You must provide at least host name to query ClickHouse // <---- !!!
> 
> Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'omitFormat' of undefined
>     at ClickHouse.query (/home/runner/node_modules/@apla/clickhouse/src/clickhouse.js:257:60)
>     at Promise (evalmachine.<anonymous>:8:26)
>     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
>     at createTable (evalmachine.<anonymous>:7:10)
>     at evalmachine.<anonymous>:17:1
>     at Script.runInContext (vm.js:133:20)
>     at Object.runInContext (vm.js:311:6)
>     at evaluate (/run_dir/repl.js:133:14)
>     at ReadStream.<anonymous> (/run_dir/repl.js:116:5)
>     at ReadStream.emit (events.js:198:13)
```

---

The code reproducing this error (see https://repl.it/repls/FakePortlyExponent):

```js
const ClickHouse = require('@apla/clickhouse')

let clickhouse = new ClickHouse (/*sails.config.clickhouse*/null); // <----- !!!
let query = `CREATE TABLE table1(category String,subcategory String,title String,id Int64) Engine=Log`;

async function createTable() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              clickhouse.query (query, function (err, result) {
                  if (err) {
                      console.log(err);
                  }
                  resolve('success');
              });
          });
}

createTable()
    .then(() => {
        console.info('Success.');
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error('Error:', err);
    });
```